# Need help deciphering equation that was messed up when used on a thread online

Tags: physics

How can I understand what this says? Can someone also tell me what the heck those symbols mean and where they came from?

$$\vec{p_e} = 1200 kg \cdot 5 m/s [{1 \over \sqrt{2}} , {1 \over \sqrt{2}}] \\
\vec{\Delta p} = \vec{p_e} - \vec{p_f} = 1200 [-{5 \over \sqrt{2}}, {15 \over \sqrt{2}}] kg m/s \\
|\vec{\Delta p}| = 1200 \sqrt{({5 \over \sqrt{2}})^2 + ({15 \over \sqrt{2}})^2} kg m/s = 1,3 \cdot 10^4 kgm/s$$

Comment: Do you understand what is shown when you enclose the symbols in dollar signs, `$$\vec{p_e} ... kgm/s$$` in the question body?

Comment: No, because I don't understand what the backslash and brackets stand for here. I assume it was corrupted when the OP made the thread.

Comment: I mean, do you understand what is now displayed?

Comment: Ah thx, did you fix my post or did it automatically correct itself? :D

Comment: I just inserted the dollar signs, so that the rendering engine knows to interpret it as $\LaTeX$ markup.

Comment: Ah thx, i'm gonna read up on this latex stuff

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. Not only can you then recognise the markup, you can also write good-looking formulae then.

Comment: @TonyK True. I guess we should roll-back. But it was the quickest way to show the OP what was the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The arrows over the symbols mean we are dealing with vectors.  These vectors are rendered in a strange format though.  The first vector gives the magnitude first ($1200 kg * 5 m/s$) then the direction $[1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}]$.  If you multiply everything out, you can get the vector in a more traditional format: $[3000\sqrt{2}, 3000\sqrt{2}] kg\cdot m/s$.

The second vector is even more confusing in its format.  The magnitude has been partially multiplied over the direction.  Finishing the multiplication yields: $[-3000\sqrt{2}, 9000\sqrt{2}]kg\cdot m/s$

The third equation is simply computing the magnitude of the second vector.  Using our more tradition form of the vector it would be: $$\left\vert \triangle p \right\vert = \sqrt{(-3000\sqrt{2})^2+(9000\sqrt{2})^2}kg \cdot m/s \approx 1,3 \times 10^4 kg \cdot m/s$$

The comma is simply the European form of a decimal point: $1,3 = 1.3$.